# tippyjs offset not working

Tags: jquery, tippyjs

I'm using [Tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) with an embedded HTML form, which is relatively large.
My problem is that when I click the trigger object that is too close to the top of the browser window, the popper gets cut off.

Tippy has an offset attribute that looks like what I need and is supposed to move the popper on the X and Y axis's, but it won't move on the Y axis, only the X.

I've tried moving the position of the popper using the placement attribute and the offset using the offset attribute but I can't figure it out.

These are examples of what it should look like and what it does look like.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution was to add "popperOptions" to the tippy initialization

```
 popperOptions: {
    modifiers: {
      preventOverflow: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  }
```

full init might look like:

```
tippy('.mySelector', {
  appendTo: document.querySelector('.mySelector').parentNode,
  popperOptions: {
    modifiers: {
      preventOverflow: {
        enabled: false
      },
      hide: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the solution was to add `preventOverflow`, not just adding `popperOptions`, right?

Comment: Ultimately, yes though I had to add popperOptions to use preventoverFlow, afaik.

Comment: Though it works, I also get 
`preventOverflow modifier is required by hide modifier in order to     work, be sure to include it before hide! `
 in the console every time I invoke tippy.